# What pkg --public does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, yarnpkg, binaryfiles

I get this issue when I run puppeteer: "The passed function is not well serializable!", but if I use --public with pkg everything works.

What --public does ?

Comment: thank god for finding your question, literally solved my issues with puppeteer i've been having for 2 months now, but It would be nice to know what it actually does too :D